# Using regularization with quantized graph in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use [Quantization-aware training](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize) for [`mobilenet_v1`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md) on my own dataset. I first train a network with `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` for the classification output, with `tf.nn.l2_loss` applied to the weights. This works as intended and I get about 70% accuracy, which is great! I then fine tune with the quantized graph with the following:

```
model = get_model()
c_ent = get_cross_ent()
wd = get_weight_decay()
loss = c_ent + 0.01 * wd #blue graph bellow
#loss = c_ent #red graph bellow

g = tf.get_default_graph()
tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph(input_graph=g,
                                      quant_delay=0)

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)
```

This is the cross entropy loss over time. The blue is with weight decay, and the red is without weight decay.

[image: Cross entropy loss]

This graph is the weight decay loss. Again, blue is with, red is without.

[image: Weight decay loss]

As you can see, when weight decay loss is added to the total loss, the cross entropy loss increases up to some value and then stays the same. Removing the weight decay loss causes the cross entropy value is decreases, but I'm almost positive it's overfitting, because the accuracy goes above that of the original network and the weight values are skyrocketing.

What is the proper way to add weight regularization in this Quantization-aware training mode?

Another strange thing is that the weight decay loss gets very close to zero, when added to the total loss.